# makeheadrule in the memoir class

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I have been trying to get the `makeheadrule` and `makefootrule` directives to work in a `memoir` class document. Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\copypagestyle{memoirStylePages}{headings}
\makerunningwidth{memoirStylePages}{\textwidth}

\makeheadrule{memoirStylePages}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{memoirStylePages}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{}

\nouppercaseheads

\makeevenhead{memoirStylePages}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddhead{memoirStylePages}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark}

\makeevenfoot{memoirStylePages}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{memoirStylePages}{}{}{}

\makepsmarks{memoirStylePages}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}
}

\pagestyle{memoirStylePages}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}    
\lipsum[1-10]    
\end{document}
```

I am unable to understand why I get the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last argument of `makefootrule` mustn't be empty. So use:

```
\makefootrule{memoirStylePages}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{0pt}
```

---

The command `\makefootrule` has the following syntax:

```
\makefootrule{ style }{ width }{ thickness }{ skip }
```

> Specifies the width and thickness of the rule drawn skip (see
>   `\footskip`) above the footers of the style pagestyle.

---

Here your modifed MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\copypagestyle{memoirStylePages}{headings}
\makerunningwidth{memoirStylePages}{\textwidth}
\makeheadrule{memoirStylePages}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makefootrule{memoirStylePages}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}{0pt}
\nouppercaseheads
\makeevenhead{memoirStylePages}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddhead{memoirStylePages}{}{}{\itshape\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{memoirStylePages}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{memoirStylePages}{}{}{}

\makepsmarks{memoirStylePages}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}
}

\pagestyle{memoirStylePages}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}    
\lipsum[1-10]    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I always get confused with which options have defaults and which don't. The "missing number" should have warned me, but I wasn't really thinking clearly then.